# Labeling the centroids of a PCoA based on betadisper() multivariate dispersions in R

Tags: r, pca, random-forest, vegan, manova

I've used the function `betadisper()` in the vegan package to generate multivariate dispersions and plot those data in a PCoA. In this example I'll be looking at the difference between the sexes in a singular species.

Load the original data. For our purposes this can legit be anything here. The data I'm using isn't special. Its feature measurements are from a bioacoustic dataset. I am walking through my process:

```
my_original_data = read.csv("mydata.csv", as.is = T, check.names = F)
#Just extract the numeric/quantitative data.
myData=my_original_data[, 13:107]
```

Based on previous research, we used an unsupervised randomForest to determine similarity within our original feature measurements:

```
require(randomForest)
full_urf = randomForest(myData, proximity=T, scale=TRUE, ntree=4999,importance = TRUE)
```

A index was then generated using the proximity matrix:

```
urf_dist_full = as.dist(1-full_urf$proximity)
```

An permutational MANOVA was run on the resulting index using the vegan package.  The use of the pMANOVA was well researched and is the correct test for my purposes:

```
mod=adonis(formula = urf_dist_full ~ Sex * Age * Variant, data = my_original_data, permutations = 999, method = "euclidean")
```

my_original_data had qualitative factors, Sex, Age and Variant.  I could have extracted them, but it seemed cleaner to keep them within the original dataset.

After running a few homogeneity tests, I want to plot the multivariate dispersions.  To do this I have been using the betadisper function:

```
Sex=betadisper(urf_dist_full,my_original_data$Sex)
plot(Sex, main="Sex Multivariate Dispersions")
```

That plots this beauty:

[image: Sex Multivariate Dispersions]

How can I label the centroids as Male and Female? I also want to run this plot for the Variant category, but that has five factors rather than two, which really warrants labeling.

I've seen the `boxplot()` variant of this, but I like how the PCoA also shows clustering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add labels to centroids like this:

```
ordilabel(scores(Sex, "centroids"))
```

where `Sex` is your `betadisper` result. If you do not want to use the original names of your centroids, you can change the names with:

```
ordilabel(scores(Sex, "centroids"), labels=c("A","B"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the identify-function:

```
A <- plot(sex)
identify(A, "centroids")
```

Or look at the scores (this don't add labels to the plot, but shows you the centroid position)

```
scores(sex, 1:2, display = "centroids")
```

Comment: Ah, I think I was a bit unclear.  I meant label the centroids "Male" and "Female". I've now changed that in the text.  Thank you for your input, though! I'm going to investigate identify.

Comment: Ah! The identify totally works!  Thank you very much!